# How many bytes does a string have

Tags: python

Is there some function which will tell me how many bytes does a string occupy in memory?

I need to set a size of a socket buffer in order to transfer the whole string at once.

Comment: So you don't care about the size of the string in memory but rather how long it is in a specific encoding. The usual way would be to convert the string into a byte array (possibly byte string in Python) in the encoding you need to transfer (UTF-8 for example) and get the length.

Comment: @Joey: I don't get you, why do you think it's the length in an encoding? Even I am facing the same issue, needing to know the size of the (string) contents to be sent over the wire. What I really need is the size, in bytes, what would I do with length of that string?

Comment: @0xc0de: “pure” Unicode **cannot** be sent over the wire unless encoded to bytes. The most common general encodings are “utf-32”, “utf-16-be”/“utf-16-le” or “utf-8” (a very sensible choice since it won't contain null bytes).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
import sys
sys.getsizeof(s)

# getsizeof(object, default) -> int
# Return the size of object in bytes.
```

But actually you need to know its represented length, so something like `len(s)` should be enough.

Comment: +1 for the function. Does this not return all the extra baggage to represent the object? The rest of the fields in the PyObject.

Comment: @Noufal - exactly. For a simple 'a' string it returns 41.

Comment: my 'a' needs 25 bytes; so either you run 64-bit Python or the font I use has simpler strokes :)

Comment: Ignoring for the moment that `sys.getsizeof()` is utterly irrelevant to the OP's problem: a size of 25 or 41 is a nonsense; `malloc()` and friends usually allocate chunks of memory whose size is a multiple of `2 ** n` where `n` is certainly greater than 1, and some of the chunk is occupied by malloc overhead and `sys.getsizeof()` doesn't allow for any of this (because it doesn't know any details of the malloc implementation).

Comment: `len(s)` won't be enough with Unicode, since many characters take up more than one byte. See tzot's answer (convert to bytes first when using Unicode).

Comment: Len works perfectly as shown in the sample below. this suggestion yields wierd results due to malloc an other structs.

Comment: I think you need to encode and then use `len`. I'm not sure about this call. `getsizeof(2)`! really 24 bytes to store number 2?!

Comment: This answer can be a bit misleading deepening on what the person is looking for - while it will return the size in memory **in python**, it may not give you the size by itself, according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof): `getsizeof() calls the object’s __sizeof__ method and adds an additional garbage collector overhead if the object is managed by the garbage collector.` Same thing for python 2

Answer (score 102):

If it's a Python 2.x `str`, get its `len`. If it's a Python 3.x `str` (or a Python 2.x `unicode`), first encode to `bytes` (or a `str`, respectively) using your preferred encoding (`'utf-8'` is a good choice) and then get the `len` of the encoded bytes/str object.

---

For example, ASCII characters use 1 byte each:

```
>>> len("hello".encode("utf8"))
5
```

whereas Chinese ones use 3 bytes each:

```
>>> len("你好".encode("utf8"))
6
```

Comment: Indeed this is the right answer. This `sys.getsizeof()` doesn't give you what you want. So, if you have a utf-8 encoded string, in stead of saying `len(myString)`, just say `len(myString.encode("utf8"))`

Comment: This should be the right answer.  It will tell you exactly how many bytes you need for the string, unicode or not.  There's a good chance the string will be encoded to bytes for transmission anyway, so I doubt there would even be a performance hit.