# Getting word counts from a file and adding suffix to the word - Python

Tags: python, string, file, tuples, counter

Given a text file, e.g.:

```
This is a foo bar sentence .
And this is the first txtfile in the corpus .
```

The goal is to get a `Counter` object with counts and its keys as a tuple of the characters of each word, i.e.:

```
Counter({('i', 's', '</w>'): 2, ('t', 'h', 'e', '</w>'): 2, ('.', '</w>'): 2, ('T', 'h', 'i', 's', '</w>'): 1, ('f', 'i', 'r', 's', 't', '</w>'): 1, ('t', 'x', 't', 'f', 'i', 'l', 'e', '</w>'): 1, ('f', 'o', 'o', '</w>'): 1, ('t', 'h', 'i', 's', '</w>'): 1, ('s', 'e', 'n', 't', 'e', 'n', 'c', 'e', '</w>'): 1, ('A', 'n', 'd', '</w>'): 1, ('b', 'a', 'r', '</w>'): 1, ('c', 'o', 'r', 'p', 'u', 's', '</w>'): 1, ('a', '</w>'): 1, ('i', 'n', '</w>'): 1})
```

I've tried to open the file, (i) read the file into list of words by spaces and (ii) then use a map lambda to split the word into character tuples and then add the `</w>` suffix to it and (iii) cast it into a Counter object:

```
$ echo -e """This is a foo bar sentence .\nAnd this is the first txtfile in the corpus .""" > test.txt
$ cat test.txt 
This is a foo bar sentence .
And this is the first txtfile in the corpus .
$ python
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> open('test.txt').read().split()
['This', 'is', 'a', 'foo', 'bar', 'sentence', '.', 'And', 'this', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'txtfile', 'in', 'the', 'corpus', '.']
>>> Counter(open('test.txt').read().split())
Counter({'is': 2, '.': 2, 'the': 2, 'a': 1, 'And': 1, 'bar': 1, 'sentence': 1, 'This': 1, 'txtfile': 1, 'this': 1, 'in': 1, 'foo': 1, 'corpus': 1, 'first': 1})
>>> Counter(map(lambda x: tuple(list(x)+['</w>']), open('test.txt').read().split()))
Counter({('i', 's', '</w>'): 2, ('t', 'h', 'e', '</w>'): 2, ('.', '</w>'): 2, ('T', 'h', 'i', 's', '</w>'): 1, ('f', 'i', 'r', 's', 't', '</w>'): 1, ('t', 'x', 't', 'f', 'i', 'l', 'e', '</w>'): 1, ('f', 'o', 'o', '</w>'): 1, ('t', 'h', 'i', 's', '</w>'): 1, ('s', 'e', 'n', 't', 'e', 'n', 'c', 'e', '</w>'): 1, ('A', 'n', 'd', '</w>'): 1, ('b', 'a', 'r', '</w>'): 1, ('c', 'o', 'r', 'p', 'u', 's', '</w>'): 1, ('a', '</w>'): 1, ('i', 'n', '</w>'): 1})
```

Imagine if the file is really huge like 2,000,000 lines and an average of 40 words per line and 10 character per word.

**Given the file size, would `open('file.txt').read().split()` be inefficient?**

**Would it be better if I read the file, line by line, then word by word into a Counter first then iterate over the counter to add the suffix and split the word into character tuples?** I.e.

```
>>> x = Counter()
>>> for line in open('test.txt'):
...     for word in line.split():
...             x[word]+=1
... 
>>> x = Counter({tuple(list(k)+['</w>']):v for k,v in x.items()})
>>> x
Counter({('i', 's', '</w>'): 2, ('t', 'h', 'e', '</w>'): 2, ('.', '</w>'): 2, ('T', 'h', 'i', 's', '</w>'): 1, ('t', 'x', 't', 'f', 'i', 'l', 'e', '</w>'): 1, ('f', 'o', 'o', '</w>'): 1, ('t', 'h', 'i', 's', '</w>'): 1, ('s', 'e', 'n', 't', 'e', 'n', 'c', 'e', '</w>'): 1, ('f', 'i', 'r', 's', 't', '</w>'): 1, ('b', 'a', 'r', '</w>'): 1, ('c', 'o', 'r', 'p', 'u', 's', '</w>'): 1, ('a', '</w>'): 1, ('i', 'n', '</w>'): 1, ('A', 'n', 'd', '</w>'): 1})
```

Is there a better way to achieve the same `Counter` object?

---

The purpose of achieving the `Counter` object above, is such that I can get a secondary `Counter` based on the continuous character pairs of the words in the vocabulary, i.e.:

```
>>> from collections import Counter                                                 
>>> from itertools import tee
>>> v = Counter(map(lambda x: tuple(list(x)+['</w>']), open('test.txt').read().split()))
>>> def pairwise(i): a,b = tee(i); next(b,None); return zip(a,b)
... 
>>> Counter(*zip(*iter(pairwise(word) for word in v)))
Counter({('t', 'h'): 2, ('t', 'x'): 1, ('f', 'o'): 1, ('a', '</w>'): 1, ('A', 'n'): 1, ('b', 'a'): 1, ('s', 'e'): 1, ('T', 'h'): 1, ('.', '</w>'): 1, ('i', 's'): 1, ('c', 'o'): 1, ('f', 'i'): 1, ('i', 'n'): 1})
```

And at the end I need both the `Counter`s such that I can use the `.most_common()` functionality:

```
Counter({('i', 's', '</w>'): 2, ('t', 'h', 'e', '</w>'): 2, ('.', '</w>'): 2, ('T', 'h', 'i', 's', '</w>'): 1, ('f', 'i', 'r', 's', 't', '</w>'): 1, ('t', 'x', 't', 'f', 'i', 'l', 'e', '</w>'): 1, ('f', 'o', 'o', '</w>'): 1, ('t', 'h', 'i', 's', '</w>'): 1, ('s', 'e', 'n', 't', 'e', 'n', 'c', 'e', '</w>'): 1, ('A', 'n', 'd', '</w>'): 1, ('b', 'a', 'r', '</w>'): 1, ('c', 'o', 'r', 'p', 'u', 's', '</w>'): 1, ('a', '</w>'): 1, ('i', 'n', '</w>'): 1})

Counter({('t', 'h'): 2, ('t', 'x'): 1, ('f', 'o'): 1, ('a', '</w>'): 1, ('A', 'n'): 1, ('b', 'a'): 1, ('s', 'e'): 1, ('T', 'h'): 1, ('.', '</w>'): 1, ('i', 's'): 1, ('c', 'o'): 1, ('f', 'i'): 1, ('i', 'n'): 1})
```

**Is `Counter(*zip(*iter(pairwise(word) for word in v)))` inefficient too?**

Comment: How are you going to use the resultant `Counter` object afterward? Are you just going to query it?

Comment: I'm going to use the Counter object afterwards.

Comment: Do you mean that you are going to add new entries to it?

Comment: If i am just going to query it, is there a more efficient way too? I could easy cast a dict back to a Counter, if the result becomes a dict.

Comment: Yeah, i'm going to add to the Counter object later, like doing a `x.update(newlist)`. But assuming that I don't need to add to the Counter, is there anyway too?

Comment: You can just create your own massive 2m+ line test file with the distribution of words you're looking for, and benchmark performance.

Comment: For queries, you can just wrap the original counter `original_counter` in a class that translates `tuple_counter[('a', 'b', 'c', '</w>')]` to `original_counter['abc']`

Comment: Are you trying to count letter-bigrams?

Comment: Nope, i'm not trying to count letter bigrams, I'm trying to do some string compression using the bigrams, I need both the vocab Counter and bigrams and also I need the `</w>` suffix to be added to each word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, it is inefficient - or so it looks like at first.

Let's approach this first from a purely high-level perspective.

`read()` reads the whole file into memory (as you are literally constructing a string from the contents of a file, for which memory needs to be allocated).

For a large file, this is prohibitive:

- Assuming each word is an alphanumeric string of exactly 10 characters, this translates to (using [`sys.getsizeof()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013230/how-many-bytes-does-a-string-have)) about 47 bytes per word.
- Take each sentence to have 40 words - that brings us upto 1880 bytes per sentence.
- Multiplying that by 2 million, and dividing by `10**9` (since a gigabyte is that much in bytes), we find that this is **a 3.76 GB file**.

By simply storing that string, you will run quickly into space constraints on 32-bit systems, and may even run up against the per-userspace process memory limits set by the operating system. Most 64-bit systems should be fine, but there is absolutely no call to be generating such high load on your system. split() on such a massive string will tax your system further, as this will *duplicate* your memory for a brief while when you build the string (since you have not deleted the string from before, though the garbage collector in Python will usually deallocate memory for the string in question once all references to it are zero in a running program).

But, we reason, reading line by line is a *streaming* process - the file itself is treated as an iterator object, and each subsequent line is lazily generated. You are not first creating a massive object and forcing Python to act on it - instead you are creating smaller objects and incrementing space allocation slowly. By the time you are done, you will still have reached 3.76 GBs in memory, but you would have done so *gracefully* by going slowly at it.

So, yes, at first glance, it *looks* like you're making a big mistake and reading line by line is a better choice.

### But does this really matter?

In other words, is our interpretation of the bottleneck actually valid?

The only way to do this is to *test*. First, some CPU information for your reference:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 42
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               800.000
BogoMIPS:              3990.96
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
```

I have 8 gigs of RAM.

I created a reference file of about 306 MB, consisting of about 727,947 lines of 40 words of length 10 (all characters were randomly generated - creating a 3 GB file would have taken too long):

```
import random
import string
with open("test.txt", "w+") as out:
    f = lambda x: ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(x))
    for i in xrange(727947):
        out.write(' '.join(f(10) for q in xrange(40)) + '\n')
```

Reading and allocating this took just two seconds:

```
akshat@Centaur:~$ time python2.7 -c 'with open("test.txt", "r") as f: f.read().split()'

real    0m1.768s
user    0m1.258s
sys     0m0.507s
```

(You may use `htop` to view the resident memory being used by this lone process in its brief existence).

Since a gigabyte is roughly 10 times 100 megabytes, we extrapolate and argue that it would take about 20 seconds to read such a massive file.

What about doing `Counter(*zip(*iter(pairwise(word) for word in v)))`? I timed the results of your program on my machine:

```
from collections import Counter                                                 
from itertools import tee
v = Counter(map(lambda x: tuple(list(x)+['</w>']), open('test.txt').read().split()))
def pairwise(i): a,b = tee(i); next(b,None); return zip(a,b)
Counter(*zip(*iter(pairwise(word) for word in v)))
```

It caused my system to hang, forcing me to try and kill the process when my computer became unresponsive:

```
akshat@Centaur:~$ time python2.7 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    v = Counter(map(lambda x: tuple(list(x)+['</w>']), open('test.txt').read().split()))


real    3m37.346s
user    1m2.196s
sys     0m4.050s
```

Note that this has not even finished! This is the result of a premature exit of the program - it took three minutes simply to *map* and apply a `Counter` to it, and it was *still* not done. Note that I had only two or three other running processes at any given moment during this interval - you are free to reproduce my results on a less busy machine, but the point will still stand.

And this is a measly 300 MB file, not even remotely close to what you want to deal with.

Let's try your other approach - reading line by line, and incrementally updating:

```
x = Counter()

for line in open('test.txt'):
    for word in line.split():
        x[word]+=1

x = Counter({tuple(list(k)+['</w>']):v for k,v in x.items()})
```

This also caused my system to crash, of course, but the line at which it crashes is particularly revealing:

```
akshat@Centaur:~$ time python2.7 test.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    x = Counter({tuple(list(k)+['</w>']):v for k,v in x.items()})
  File "test.py", line 8, in <dictcomp>
    x = Counter({tuple(list(k)+['</w>']):v for k,v in x.items()})
KeyboardInterrupt

real    4m26.686s
user    2m7.868s
sys     0m3.017s
```

We already know that *reading* the file was not a major bottleneck, since we already tested how long that takes in our supposed worst case.

Even more interesting is that `Counter()` hasn't even yet begun to play into it at all. I tested both versions without using `Counter()` in the line that caused a hang and found that simply applying a `map()` or doing a dictionary comprehension alone will cause my system to hang - neither finishes in less than five minutes, meaning they themselves were responsible for the massive runtimes we were seeing.

No, instead the bottleneck *always* arrives when we are trying to map something over the contents of the file. **This is the most memory-hogging bit of the program**, and takes several minutes for it to complete for even a moderately sized file.

(If someone cares to actually let the two complete side by side, I will happily update my answer here to reflect those figures).

### So what have we learned?

- The inefficiency is in *mapping over your list*.
- It is *not* in using `read()` or using `readlines()` - they take literally 0.66 percent of the total time (two seconds out of an upper bound of five minutes by both maps). Even if we assume growth is linear with the size of the input, that proportion will not change.
- [Premature optimization is the root of all evil.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)

You are worrying about the wrong thing altogether.

Your bottleneck is in trying to apply a fairly complex operation to a fairly bulky list held in memory, even though this list is supposedly ten times smaller than the range you want to deal with. Nothing you can do at the Python level can fix it.

It is that simple. Fix *that*:

- Either by trying to bundle as much computation as you can in each line of data and then incrementally adding them up to form a larger object, with no guarantees this will help, or
- Parallelising your work. The problem of generating a *count* for a given word falls easily into the [MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) paradigm, and using Apache Spark or similar on an appropriate cluster will aid you greatly in coming up with a reference mapping.

Comment: For bonus points, you may even want to apply `strace` to the running program and see how many system calls it makes at any given moment.

Answer (score -1):

Counter looks like it may just be a dictionary. With reading the file, you can just read line by line using `readline()`, rather than reading the whole thing in with `read()` and then having to iterate over it a second time to do the work.

The below will read lines from a file line by line, strip the endline character if needed, then transform the words into the character tuples you specified. Then it adds or increments the entry in the dictionary.

```
fp = 'some_filepath'
counter = {}
with open(fp) as fid:
    line = fid.readline()
    while line != '':
        line = line[:-1] if line[-1:] == '\n' else line
        words = [tuple(list(x) + ['</w>']) for x in line.split(' ')]
        for word in words:
            counter[word] = counter[word] + 1 if word in counter else 1
        line = fid.readline()
    fid.close()
```

Comment: The `do-while` loop with `readline()` could have been replaced by the `for line in fid:`, and the `line = line[:-1]` could be replaced with `line.strip()`.  And as for the `counter[word]+=1 if ...`, that could have been replaced with the `collections.Counter` object.

Comment: `Counter` is a subclass of `dict`, but the bigger issue is this doesn't actually answer the question. The question asks if a proposed method is *inefficient*, not on how to a particular thing.

Comment: @alvas asked if `open('file.txt').read().split()` would be inefficient and if "there a better way to achieve the same Counter object?". In my answer I've shown a better way (albeit to a dict not a Counter) that takes away the memory constraint.